# Error 500 react native

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Al querer iniciar un proyecto de react native en linux mint con android studio (Sdk + Avd), me lanza el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información del package.json es:

```
{
  "name": "miot",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No esta encontrando los módulos necesarios, podrías ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun la pantalla en roja, no se estan instalando correctamente las depencias, asi ejecuta:
`rm -rf node_module` y luego `npm i`.
Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta que estás en ambiente de Linux es un problema común que no esté el runtime de babel dentro de proyecto y en general, puedes ejecutar los siguientes comandos para añadir el runtime e intentar de nuevo

Intenta usando

```
npm add @babel/runtime 
npm install
```

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué tu propuesta soluciona el problema.